# SCSS Intellisense doesn't show up variables from imported scss files

Tags: sass, less, intellisense, vscode-extensions

I installed **SCSS IntelliSense extenstion** in VS Code but it doesnt suggest any of available variables from other **.scss** files

It look like this:

[image: problem itself]

One of my .scss files which i imported:
[image: global variables]

What i've already tried to do:

1. reinstalled SCSS IntelliSense extenstion;
2. checked extenstion settings, rule "Suggest variables" is **ON**;
3. disable and enable back all extenstions which may cause this problem (prettier, eslint, stylelint etc...);

How do i fix it?

Comment: instead of this extension use [vscode-css-variables](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=SCSS%20IntelliSense%20extenstion&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance). Also you should raise this issue on that particular extensions's github repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by installing [CSS Variable Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vunguyentuan.vscode-css-variables) extenstion

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).